# Bash script to execute SQL command not working

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following SELECT statement for a PostgreSQL database to be executed from a bash script:

```
psql -U chh1 -d crewdb -c "SELECT SETVAL('date_link_date_linkid_seq', (SELECT MAX(date_linkid) FROM date_link), true);"
```

This would be the desired syntax for the command to be executed in the script. I want to replace date_link with a variable that is read from STDIN. To this end I have written the following bash script:

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 
  3 echo "Please enter the table name: "
  4 read -r var
  5 
  6 
  7 echo 'psql -U chh1 -d crewdb -c "SELECT SETVAL('"${var}"_"${var}id_seq"', (SELECT MAX("${var}id") FROM "$var"), true);"'
```

When I run it the SELECT MAX(.. part is not working and I get the following output:

```
psql -U chh1 -d crewdb -c "SELECT SETVAL(date_link_date_linkid_seq, (SELECT MAX("${var}id") FROM "$var"), true);"
```

Can you please help?

Comment: your select setval is outside of quotation marks

Comment: thanks Zina I repaired that but SELECT MAX(... is till not working.

Comment: well, you are echo-ing it - that is like print to screen - so not sure what you expect. if you want to run the command - remove the echo and I still think your quotation marks are missed...

Comment: I know that I have to remove echo if I want to run it. The command will not run because $var is not passing on date_link in the SELECT MAX(.... part. If I can get a correct echo I will remove it and run the command by itself.

Comment: try `b="'"` and then `echo 'psql -U chh1 -d crewdb -c "SELECT SETVAL('''$b${var}'_'${var}id_seq''$b', (SELECT MAX('''${var}id''') FROM '''$var'''), true);"'`

Comment: You are right, Zena. I missed quotation marks around SELECT SETVAL. I have updated line 7 to `echo 'psql -U chh1 -d crewdb -c '"SELECT SETVAL('"${var}"_"${var}id_seq"', (SELECT MAX("${var}id") FROM "$var"), true);"''
`. This works. Thank your very much!

Comment: yeah, yours is easier - LOL - a bit late for me - overthinking stuff....